# use of 'require' in 3rd party browser js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript app is a client-side app. It **does not** run in NodeJS and it **does not** use Require.js, AMD, or ComponentJS.

However, certain 3rd party JS libraries intended for use in the client, use the `require` method. Here are 2 examples in heavily used client-side libraries:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L26

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L264

Does usage of those libraries mean that I need to include RequireJS, AMD, or ComponentJS? Is 'require' function usage in the client becoming so common place that I *have* to make sure it's defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to use `require()` or an environment/library that defines it. But, it is an option.

Each script is just trying to support multiple module patterns/systems at once, using `require()` if it's available. Before using it, they check for the existence of other objects related to CommonJS Modules:

```
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
```

```
if (!locales[name] && typeof module !== 'undefined' &&
        module && module.exports) {
```

---

Though, in the case of `moment.js`, you'll just need to include locales via `<script>`s. `loadLocale()` can be used to access any already loaded, but can't actually load more without `require()`.

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="locales/es.js"></script>
<script>
    var es = loadLocale('es');
</script>
```

---

Some common patterns for supporting mixed systems, like these are doing, are documented by the [`umdjs/umd` project](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

Comment: So if I'm seeing errors stating that 'require is not defined' then is that just the libraries testing for the existence of that function?

Comment: Also, I know that there is still a lot of progress going on in this area, but what's the current recommendation on supporting 'require'?